# CCRenderTexture "Scratch Off" getUiimage leaves outline

Tags: ios, image, cocos2d-iphone

I have successfully implemented "Scratch Off" functionality using Steve Oldmeadow's example.
Then I create a sprite from the render texture.

My problem is that the image has an outline around it. Thinking it has something to do with blending/transparency, but can't figure out how to get rid of the outline.

Thanks for any help.

Relevant Code:

```
-(id) init
{
 burnSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"burn100.png"];
 [burnSprite setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc) { GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }];

 scratchOffImage = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"foot.png"] retain];
 scratchLayer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:size.width height:size.height];
 scratchLayer.position =  ccp(size.width*.5 , size.height*.5);
 [[scratchLayer sprite] setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }];
 [self addChild:scratchLayer z:20];

. . .


- (void) drawTexture {
    [scratchLayer begin];

    glColorMask(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);      // Limit drawing to the alpha channel
    [burnSprite visit];                       // Draw
    glColorMask(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);      // Reset color mask

    [scratchLayer end];
}    


-(void)getImage{
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:[scratchLayer getUIImage].CGImage   key:@"myNewImage"];
    sprite.position = foot.position;
    [self addChild:sprite z:40];
```

Comment: Does your texture have nice clean edges, and no partial transparency? If not, it needs to be so(pixels need to be either full alpha or no alpha). Also, by default textures are loaded anti-aliased. You'll want to try setting the tex parameters to aliased. ([spr.texture setAliasTexParameters] )

Comment: Thanks! Was exactly the problem.